# Error when adding total quantity fetched by MYSQL Query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I want to add the quantity of pants to display the total pants in the database but it only shows nothing.. this is the coding.. is my logic is wrong?

```
<?php
if(is_resource($r) and mysql_num_rows($r)>0)
{
       while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q))
       {
            $p = mysql_query("SELECT qtt FROM stock_request WHERE branch_id = 'bachok' AND type = 'Pants'") or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());

            $tp = $tp + $p;
        }
        echo $tp;
                          }
?>
```

Comment: Have a look at how [mysql_query()](http://php.net/mysql_query) works. If you scroll past the "do not use this extension" red warning you'll find a complete usage example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong Logic as  **[mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)** returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error. It does not return the value(quantity in your case).

In order to fetch a value in an array, use **[mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)** — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both.

Initialise `$tp=0` before while loop

Replace `$tp = $tp + $p;` with

```
$tp=$tp+$r[0]
```

Here is the complete code:

```
<?php

       $p = mysql_query("SELECT qtt FROM stock_request WHERE branch_id = 'bachok' AND type = 'Pants'") ;
       $tp=0;
       while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($p,MYSQL_NUM))
       {
             $tp = $tp + $r[0];
       }
        echo $tp;

?>
```

UPDATE:
What's the meaning of $r[0]?

**[mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)** can be used in three ways:

- mysql_fetch_array() with MYSQL_NUM
- mysql_fetch_array() with MYSQL_ASSOC
- mysql_fetch_array() with MYSQL_BOTH

I had used $r=0 ie. mysql_fetch_array with MYSQL_NUM.

In this case, you only get number indices. For example :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT a,b,c,d,e FROM mytable");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
```

$row [0] means value of a

$row [ 1] means value of b

$row [ 2] means value of c

............

$row[4]=means value of e.

Thus in your query, $r[0] refers to value of **qtt**

Comment: @Nama Saya Din: **meaning of $r[0]** -> Please check my Update. :)

Comment: thanks again..i must see those DB as an array now..i am now quite dizzy imagine it like an array..with those explanation,i'm now quite understand the concept of array in DB. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong:

```
$p = mysql_query("SELECT qtt FROM stock_request WHERE branch_id = 'bachok' AND type = 'Pants'") or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
```

should be:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT qtt FROM stock_request WHERE branch_id = 'bachok' AND type = 'Pants'") or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$p = $row['qtt'];
```

Comment: thanks for the correction but still there are no data displayed.